# Forward values from custom HttpControllerSelector and HttpActionSelector to its descriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 Web API which returns a custom response in case of unexpected exceptions or if the controller or action were not found. Essentially, I've done exactly as shown there: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api Everything's working like a charm.

The problem is: I'd like to submit the error code from `SelectController()` and `SelectAction()` to my `ErrorController`. This way I would not have duplicate code and all the logic would be in the controller.

Unfortunately, I do not find any possible way to submit the error code to my controller. All the examples are redirecting to a specific error action (e.g. `ErrorController.NotFound404`) I'd like to redirect to `ErrorController.Main` and do all the magic there.

Another issue with the custom `ApiControllerActionSelector` is that the `Request` property is `null` in the `ErrorController`. This problem does not exist with the custom `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, I was able to find the solution myself. Let me show you how I got it up and running.

1. The custom controller and action selector are forwarding the requested language and the current HTTP response code:

```cs
public class CustomDefaultHttpControllerSelector: DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public CustomDefaultHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try
        {
            descriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException e)
        {
            var routeValues = request.GetRouteData().Values;
            routeValues.Clear();
            routeValues["controller"] = "Error";
            routeValues["action"] = "Main";
            routeValues["code"] = e.Response.StatusCode;
            routeValues["language"] = request.Headers?.AcceptLanguage?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? "en";

            descriptor = base.SelectController(request);
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}

public class CustomControllerActionSelector: ApiControllerActionSelector
{
    public CustomControllerActionSelector()
    {
    }

    public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        HttpActionDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try
        {
            descriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException e)
        {
            var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
            routeData.Values.Clear();
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Main";
            routeData.Values["code"] = e.Response.StatusCode;
            routeData.Values["language"] = controllerContext.Request?.Headers?.AcceptLanguage?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? "en";
            IHttpController httpController = new ErrorController();
            controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
            controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Configuration, "Error", httpController.GetType());
            descriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

Two important changes:

1.1. The list of route values needs to be cleared. Otherwise it tries to find an action in the `ErrorController` which maps to this list of values.

1.2. The `code` and `language` were added.

2. The `ErrorController` itself:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("error")]
public class ErrorController: BaseController
{
    [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    [Route("{code}/{language}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Main(string code, string language)
    {
        HttpStatusCode parsedCode;
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        if (!Enum.TryParse(code, true, out parsedCode))
        {
            parsedCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        responseMessage.StatusCode = parsedCode;
        ...
    }
}
```

3. I've removed the route mapping `routes.MapHttpRoute(...)`. No matter what I've entered in the browser, it never called `Handle404`.
4. HTTP status 400 (bad request) was not covered, yet. This could be easily achieved by using the `ValidationModelAttribute` as described on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api (section "Handling Validation Errors").

Maybe this will help someone...

Comment: Point 1.1 helped someone. :)